# Deleting elementary OS drive made Windows drive not bootable

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, bios, elementaryos

I have several drives, but the only ones that matter in this case are 2 SSDs. One has a Windows 10 install on it, the other has elementary OS.

I didn't want the elementary install anymore, so I plugged in my Windows install USB drive and deleted all partitions on the drive that elementary was installed on.

**Restarted and went to check my boot priority - my Windows 10 drive is no longer bootable. It recognizes it, along with my other drives, but doesn't show it as an option to boot from.**

I cannot fathom how this could possibly happen. I absolutely did not touch that drive whatsoever, and I'm 100% sure I deleted the correct SSD. They are two different sizes, so I knew it was the one with the smaller size.

I installed Windows on the drive I wiped, and all of the files from the other drive are still on that drive. I'm copying over the ones I need, and see no issues at all with the drive. I'm going to just use this smaller drive for my Windows install instead. Really just curious at this point what the issue might be.

Answer (score 1):

Likely the elementary OS had a boot manager on it, functionally similar to Grub for many Linux installations.  That boot manager knew how to start W10.

If you have a Windows recovery disk or stick, boot from that, and it should offer to fix the W10 boot problem.

Comment: That would make sense. Although it wasn't changing how my boot functioned, so what a useless boot manager... I tried the option on the recovery stick that said "Fix boot issues" or something, and it failed of course. Didn't see any other options that would be useful in there. Probably possible, but I'm just going to use my fresh install since I can access the files from the old install.

Comment: Sorry to hear that.  I had similar once, and Windows recovery straightened it right out.